# CSS width "px" adjusts my input textfield but not "%"

Tags: css, primeflex

I have an input textfield that I would like to fill the entire grid column (using primeflex). I thought that simply adding "width: 100%" (w-full) would fix the empty space. It does not seem to adjust even with "w-full" having "!important".

I tried adjusting it manually like putting "width:200px;" but this does not seem to be dynamic thats why I want to just have it as "width: 100%". For context, my text field is under class="field".

```
<div class="field">
  <dt class="w-1">住所</dt>
  <div>
    <input class="p-inputtext p-component w-full" data-pc-name="inputtext" data-pc-section="root">
  </div>
</div>
```

- w-full is not working as intened
- class="field" has the following:

> ```
> display: flex;
> flex-direction: row;
> margin: 0;
> margin-top: 1px;
> margin-bottom: 1px;
> ```

- Note: in my input class, adding `style="width:100%"` does not work but adding `style="width:500px"` somehow does. Again my intention is to not add a manual length to have it still be dynamic.

Comment: Try putting `w-full` class on its parent `<div>` element as well.

Comment: As a sidenote: Please note the invalid usage of `dt`. It is only allowed as a child element of `dl`.

Comment: thanks for the point, that code is only a snippet. I have `dl` outside of it

Comment: ok turns out i just have to do w-full twice, thank you

Comment: It doesn't matter. `<dt>` cannot be the child of a `<div>`. Your HTML is still invalild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div class="w-full">
    <input class="w-full p-inputtext p-component w-full" data-pc-name="inputtext" data-pc-section="root">
  </div>
```

So I only just had to put the full with both in `div` and `input` in order for it to work.